# How to couple physical laws in classical physics?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I have tried to summarize classical physical laws

Gravity

$
f_g = \rho_g (-d\phi_g)\\
\star(-\Delta\phi_g)=(-4\pi G)\rho_g\\
$

Electromagnetism

$
f_e=\rho_e(-d\phi_e-\partial_tA_e+\star(v\wedge (\star(dA_e)))\\
\star(-\Delta \phi_e +c^{-2}\partial_t^2\phi_e)=\epsilon_0^{-1}\rho_e\\
\star(-\Delta A_e +c^{-2}\partial_t^2 A_e)=\mu_0j_e\\
$

Where I used hodge star $\star$ and Laplace Beltrami operator
$
\Delta=d\delta+\delta d\\
$

Momentum density transport

$
\partial_tj_m+\star d\star (j_m v)=s_{j_m}=\sum f=f_s+f_b=\star d \star\sigma + \rho_m\rho_m^{-1}f_b=\star d \star\sigma + \rho_m\rho_m^{-1}(f_g+f_e)
$

Mass transport

$
\partial_t\rho_m + \star d \star (\rho_m v)=s_{\rho_m}
$

Energy transport

$
\partial_t\rho_E+\star d \star (\rho_Ev)=s_{\rho_E}=\langle\langle \sum f,v\rangle\rangle
$

Inertial mass and "gravitational charge" equal
$
\rho_m\approx\rho_g
$

Is this the correct way to couple gravity and electromagnetism in classical physics/fluid dynamics, just add some constitutive laws? I don't see where entropy production belongs though, could someone give hint?